# Print personalized scientific notation in Python

Tags: python

The question is simple: If I have a number `x = 2.8e-11` and I want to print it in this format: `2.8 · 10^(-11)`, what should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this with string operations.

```
>>> x = 2.8e-11
>>> if 'e' in str(x):
    print(str(x).replace('e', ' · 10^(') + ')')

    
2.8 · 10^(-11)
```